# Array type casting in C

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have a program as given below, and I am learning type casting in C.  Here I am trying to cast void* into int*. But the compiler is throwing an error saying "`error: operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required - printf("%d\n",(int *)(a[2]));`"

Appreciate your help to do this type casting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(void* a){
        printf("%d\n",(int *)(a[2]));

}

int main(){
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
        printArray(a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(int *)(a[2]))` ==> `((int*)a)[2]` . Your code attempts to get the second slot value of a non-indexible sequence, then cast it to `int*`. You want to cast the pointer to `int*`, then get the second slot value in the (assumed) `int` sequence.

Comment: You have to cast before you dereference. otherwise the compiler doesnt know the size of the type and cant calculate the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[2]` is equivalent to *(a + 2). `a` is a `void *`, so you are dereferencing a `void *` which is ilegal.

You should cast `a` to `int *` and then dereference it, like so:

```
*((int *)a + 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the expression with the subscript operator

```
a[2]
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. This expression is evaluated like

```
*( a + 2 )
```

In turn this expression `a + 2` is evaluated in fact like

```
( char * )a + 2 * sizeof( *a )
```

But the type `void` is an incomplete type That is its size is unknown. So the compiler has no information what is the value of the expression `sizeof( *a )` where `*a` has the type `void`. And as a result it issues an error message.

What you need to write is at first to cast the pointer `a` of the type `void *` to the type `int *`

So the call of `printf` can look like

```
printf("%d\n", ( ( int * )a )[2] );
```

or

```
printf("%d\n", *( (int *)a + 2) );
```